# Visual Studio can't see methods from DLLs but compilation is OK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference, ide

I have problem with VS 2013. VS can't see anything from my DLLs but compilation is OK and project works properly. How can i fix that?

[image]

thx for your help

Comment: So your program compiles and **runs** ok?  (love the hand-drawn arrow by the way ;) )

Comment: yup. program runs ok and compilation as well

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the solution? Is it possible that you have two DLLs that are providing the same classes?

Comment: Had this in the past and it is the usual technical fix. Clean Solution and then try closing and re-opening VS2013. The Intellisense seems to get stuck sometimes.

Comment: Are you using Resharper?  Sometimes Resharper incorrectly shows things as red/not-defined even though they are.  Try restarting VS

Comment: yes, i am using Resharper.. I restarted VS milion times and still not working.

Nope, i have not 2 or more dlls that are providing the same classes

Comment: Have you tried clearing the ReSharper caches? ReSharper > Options > General > Clear Caches? Also, what does ReSharper say if you hover the mouse over the missing using statements?

Comment: now i did it and it's still not working. When i hover the mouse over the missing using statements, it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'KarsaMonitor' Using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed"

Comment: Ok. i determined that it causes resharper. when is resharper suspended, IDE works fine.